# 2 accounts reference 2 different master pages?

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

This is puzzling me for awhile.
I am developing a SharePoint MOSS 2007 site.
I have one set of accounts, who have no issues accessing the site and using correct master page.
When I use the second set of Windows user accounts, they use completely different master page for unknown to me reason.
There is no logical separation between those groups, meaning that 1 account from 1 department may behave correctly, and another account form the same department, who should have the same privileges, references a different master page.

When I try to programmatically see what the master page is, it displays the same standard default path as for other users, "_catalogs/masterpage/default.master".

The strange thing is that it seems that this different master page is really the same, but the older version of it.
Did anyone experienced the same issue?
How do I fix this? 
How do I find out what the second master page really is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in and also approved the master pager after editing it, so that the new version is available for everyone?

Comment: Thank for your reply. Yes, it is checked in. After some research, I cam into conclusion that it does have to do with different user permissions afterall.